# Campagnolo single speed conversion - can I use a 10sp cog?

Tags: single-speed, conversion, campagnolo

I have a set of Miche reflex wheels.
I would like to use them for a single speed conversion project on a Peugeot frame.

can I use a 10sp cog?
what I mean is:
can I use one of the normal cogs that are on one of my 10 speed campag cassette to do it?

This would allow me to use all the gear that I have like:
 - 10 speed chain (after being shortened)
 - original 10 speed chainring
 - one of the 10 speed cogs

Comment: I already have spacers from another conversion kit to use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible with a free-hub style hub, but you may run into some issues.

You can use a sprocket from a 10 speed cassette, and replace the other sprockets with spacers. You can place the sprocket in the spacer stack to achieve good chain alignment.

I don't know how Campagnalo cassettes are built but Shimano cassettes combine the largest sprockets onto a spider, so you would not be able to use those individually.

Cassette sprockets are of course designed to enable the chain to come of them easily when shifting, so they are not as good as retaining the chain as a purpose made single-speed sprocket. For the same reason you may have an issue with the chain coming off the chainring without a front derailleur. This is why 1x systems use a 'double-wide' chainring for better chain retention.

Sheldon Brown has a page that deals with single speeds: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/singlespeed.html, find the section titled 'Cassette Hubs'.

Comment: With Campagnolo it depends. Low end groups have loose cogs, high end has spiders with multiple cogs. Never held together with screws like some Shimano cassettes.

Comment: hey guys,
love your answer.

Comment: so, the cassette I have has single sprockets. Of course I would not expect it to last as a single speed cog, but will do the job to try it!
I have as well some spacers I can use.

Comment: so if the chain ring is a 42t what cog would you use?
19?
16?

Comment: You'll have to figure out what gearing works for you. I'm not into single speeds myself but I assume there are some commonly used ratios.

Comment: I would say this is correct except the real problem with this plan is a 10s Campy cog used like this is going to get worn out really fast on a bike that gets ridden, which is kind of a waste of money considering the value of any viable Campy cassette. Surprisingly I do see singlespeed cassette cogs available for Campy freehubs when I google it. Chain retention can be an issue when doing this kind of hack with a sprung tensioner on a vertical dropout bike, but not on horizontal dropout bikes.

Comment: Very true, it is actually quite easy to buy a single sprocket for Campag.

Comment: I just don't want to spend around 40/50 pound in components and just have a little bit of fun :)

Comment: I just read the article @ArgentiApparatus posted. Very interesting info in there. Thanks

Comment: Also consider that a single cog taken from a cassette is quite thin and it could easily wear a grove into the freehub when in constant use. Cassette cogs do this too, but on cassettes the load shifts between cogs and it's not always the same position that is under load.